# FSMountServerVolumeSync showing unwanted dialog when connection fails, how to remove?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-services

I am using FSMountServerVolumeSync to mount an afp share. All works fine, unless the connection to the server does not work. I wrote code to handle this gracefully and retry later (this is for a background process). However each time the connection fails I get this nasty popup from MacOSX :

"There was a problem connecting to the server ....."

This is very annoying. Is there a way to avoid this popup?

Comment: What parameters are being passed to the FSMountServerVolumeSync? Are you passing username,password as well? What is the type of failure for which the error popsup?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507006/determine-if-a-network-share-exists-before-mounting mentions an unsupported way.