# AppleScript: Make conditions for different error number

Tags: macos, applescript

So I'm mounting different smb shares, and want to display a relevant text according to the error number, and do nothing for the numbers I have not defined.

Sort of what i'm looking for:

```
on error
if error_number - 5014 then
            display dialog "Can't connect to" & chosen as text
        else if error_number - 5016 then
            display dialog "Can't connect to" & chosen as text
        else if error_number then --do nothing
end if
```

---

Right now I get this popup from MacOSX :

"There was a problem connecting to the server ....."

and then then my defined error message. How do I get rid of the double popup? I prefer just getting my notification, not the one from the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy because `error` provides an optional parameter `number`

```
on error errorMessage number errorNumber
    if errorNumber = -36 then
        display dialog "Can't connect to" & chosen as text
    else if errorNumber = 5016 then
        display dialog "Catch error 5016"
    end if -- ignore all other errors   
end try
```

**Edit:**

To mount volumes without error dialog boxes use the shell commands `mount_afp` or `mount_smbfs`.

This is an example for `AFP`.
It checks if the volume is already mounted. If not it creates the mount point "manually" and mounts the volume. On failure the mount point will be deleted. The `SMB` version works accordingly.

```
property server : "myServer.local"
property serverVolume : "Server"
property user : "user"
property pass : "pass"

set isMounted to serverVolume is in (do shell script "/bin/ls /Volumes") or mountAFP(user, pass, server, serverVolume)

if isMounted then
    -- do something
end if

on mountAFP(user_name, pass_word, thehost, theVolume)
    set theAddress to quoted form of ("afp://" & user_name & ":" & pass_word & "@" & thehost & "/" & theVolume)
    set mountpoint to quoted form of ("/Volumes/" & theVolume)
    try
        do shell script "/bin/mkdir " & mountpoint & "; /sbin/mount_afp " & theAddress & space & mountpoint
        return true
    on error e
        log e
        do shell script "/bin/rm -r " & mountpoint
        return false
    end try
end mountAFP
```

Comment: Works fine to get the error conditions, but not to remove the OS popup. Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507006/determine-if-a-network-share-exists-before-mounting) thread that address the issue, but it involves Private Frameworks so it's not ideal...